# How does elasticsearch prevent cascading failure after node outage due to disk pressure?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, replication, diskspace, redundancy

We operate an elasticsearch stack which uses 3 nodes to store log data. Our current config is to have indices with 3 primaries and 1 replica. (We have just eyeballed this config and are happy with the performance, so we decided to not (yet) spend time for optimization)

After a node outage (let's assume a full disk), I have observed that elasticsearch automatically redistributes its shards to the remaining instances - as advertised.

However this increases disk usage on the remaining two instances, making it a candidate for cascading failure.

Durability of the log data is not paramount. I am therefore thinking about reconfiguring elasticsearch to not create a new replica after a node outage. Instead, it could just run on the primaries only. This means that after a single node outage, we would run without redundancy. But that seems better than a cascading failure. (This is a one time cost)

An alternative would be to just increase disk size. (This is an ongoing cost)

### My question

(How) can I configure elasticsearch to not create new replicas after the first node has failed? Or is this considered a bad idea and the canonical way is to just increase disk capacity?

Answer (score 1):

### Rebalancing is expensive

When a node leaves the cluster, some additional load is generated on the remaining nodes:

- Promoting a replica shard to primary to replace any primaries that were on the node.
- Allocating replica shards to replace the missing replicas (assuming there are enough nodes).
- Rebalancing shards evenly across the remaining nodes.

This can lead to quite some data being moved around.

Sometimes, a node is only missing for a short period of time. A full rebalance is not justified in such a case. To take account for that, when a node goes down, then elasticsearch immediatelly promotes a replica shard to primary for each primary that was on the missing node, **but then it waits for one minute before creating new replicas** to avoid unnecessary copying.

### Only rebalance when required

The duration of this delay is a tradeoff and can therefore be configured. Waiting longer means less chance of useless copying but also more chance for downtime due to reduced redundancy.

Increasing the delay to a few hours results in what I am looking for. It gives our engineers some time to react, before a cascading failure can be created from the additional rebalancing load.

I learned that from the official [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/delayed-allocation.html).